# How to set up AzureSQL Database with AlwaysEncrypted and fill it with data?

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, always-encrypted

at the moment I am working with the Azure Cloud. I want to set up an AzureSQL database and use AlwaysEncrypted to ensure that the data is 'always encrypted' ;-). Furthermore I would like to set up AzureFunctions which are able to connect to the Database as well as write records in.

I already set up an AzureSQL Database but I do not know how to work with it. I started two attempts:

1. Set up table directly in SSMS, fill data in table, create keys and encrypt it with the wizard. This works totally fine and I am able to see the plain data only if I set the 'AlwaysEncrypted' Checkbox while Connecting to the database.
2. My second attempt was to include the 'always encrypt directly in the queries. I tried the following:

```
CREATE COLUMN MASTER KEY CMK_test_1   
    WITH (  
        KEY_STORE_PROVIDER_NAME = 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT',  
        KEY_PATH = '<PATH_TO_AZURE_KEY_VAULT>'   
         )   

CREATE COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY CEK_test_1   
WITH VALUES  
  (  
    COLUMN_MASTER_KEY = CMK_test_1,   
    ALGORITHM = 'RSA_OAEP',  
    ENCRYPTED_VALUE = <VALUE>
  )

Create Table dbo.AlwaysEncryptedTest
(
    ID int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , FirstName varchar(25) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (  
        ENCRYPTION_TYPE = RANDOMIZED,  
        ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
        COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = CEK_test_1) not NULL    
    , LastName varchar(25) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (  
        ENCRYPTION_TYPE = RANDOMIZED,  
        ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
        COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = CEK_test_1) not NULL
    , City varchar(25) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (  
        ENCRYPTION_TYPE = RANDOMIZED,  
        ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
        COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = CEK_test_1) not NULL
    , StreetName varchar(25) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (  
        ENCRYPTION_TYPE = RANDOMIZED,  
        ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
        COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = CEK_test_1) not NULL
)
```

I know that I have to use an application to put records in the database but I could not find a tutorial or something else that helps me to do so. I found some C# explenation on the Microsoft website but this did not help me to do the job. In best case I would write the connection in python.

Any help is appreciated.

Best
P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect Azure SQL server which enables `always encrypt` with Azure key vault in python application, we can use ODBC driver to implement it.

Regarding how to implement it, we need to add `ColumnEncryption=Enabled` into connection string to tell odbc application always encrypt has been enabled. Besides, since we use Azure key vault store, we also need to add `KeyStoreAuthentication` `KeyStorePrincipalId` and `KeyStoreSecret` to make ODBC application connect Azure key vault, get encryption key.
For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#using-the-azure-key-vault-provider) and [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/133)

For example

1. Create a service principal to connect Azure key vault

```
az login
az ad sp create-for-rbac --skip-assignment --sdk-auth

az keyvault set-policy --name $vaultName --key-permissions get, list, sign, unwrapKey, verify, wrapKey --resource-group $resourceGroupName --spn <clientId-of-your-service-principal>
```

2. Code

```
server = '<>.database.windows.net'
database = ''
username = ''
password = ''   
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
KeyStoreAuthentication='KeyVaultClientSecret'
KeyStorePrincipalId='<clientId-of-your-service-principal>'
KeyStoreSecret='<clientSecret-of-your-service-principal>'
conn_str=f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};PORT=1443;DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password};ColumnEncryption=Enabled;KeyStoreAuthentication={KeyStoreAuthentication};KeyStorePrincipalId={KeyStorePrincipalId};KeyStoreSecret={KeyStoreSecret}'
with pyodbc.connect(conn_str) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Patients]")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row:
            print (row)
            row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: tnaks you so much for your help. I will try this as soon as I have some time :-)

Comment: @Pet Do you have any other concerns?